Applying a function to all imputed datasets at once?
Thank you so much in advance for your help! Long story short, I am trying to get data ready for a mixed effects model after imputing 50 data sets.
I have an object BP.3_impute_list which contains  50 extracted imputed data sets from mids object BP.3_impute [code = BP.3_impute_list <- complete(BP.3_impute, "all")]
Here is a list of the variables within each of the datasets:
Participant_ID_New, DataWave, location, ParticipantCondition, Age_, wl1_thinideal, w2_thinideal, w1_bodydis, w2_bodydis, w1_negaff, w2_negaff, w1_comm, w2_comm, w1_bodycomp, w2_bodycomp, w1binge, w1bingechar, w1ed8a, w1ed10a, w1ed11a, w1ed14, w1ed16, w1ed18, w2binge, w2bingechar, w2ed8a, w2ed10a, w2ed11a, w2ed14, w2ed16, w2ed18
The variables ("w1binge", "w1bingechar", "w1ed8a", "w1ed9a", "w1ed10a", "w1ed11a", "w1ed14", "w1ed16", "w1ed18", "w2binge", "w2bingechar", "w2ed8a", "w2ed9a", "w2ed10a", "w2ed11a", "w2ed14", "w2ed16", "w2ed18") need to be standardized.
Then, from the standardized variables 2 new variables need to be created. The first is w1_eddi_total and is the sum of the standardized version of: "w1binge", "w1bingechar", "w1ed8a", "w1ed9a", "w1ed10a", "w1ed11a", "w1ed14", "w1ed16", "w1ed18". The second is w2_eddi_total and is the sum of the standardized version of"w2binge", "w2bingechar", "w2ed8a", "w2ed9a", "w2ed10a", "w2ed11a", "w2ed14", "w2ed16", "w2ed18".
Then, after the new total scores are created, the datasets need to be converted into long form so that all variables starting with w1_ are one time period and the variables starting with w2_ are a second time period. I also want to remove the variables originally used to create the new total scores in order to simplify the dataset.
Then the datasets need to be converted back into a mice object that allows the following analysis:
Would anyone be able to provide insight as to how I might fix this function or is there an easier way to approach this task? Thank you!
The code for the standardization and summing works:
BP.3_impute_list <- complete(BP.3_impute, "all")

# Standardize variables in each imputed dataset
standardize_vars <- function(df) {
  vars_to_standardize <- c("w1binge", "w1bingechar", "w1ed8a", "w1ed10a", "w1ed11a", "w1ed14", "w1ed16", "w1ed18", 
                           "w2binge", "w2bingechar", "w2ed8a", "w2ed10a", "w2ed11a", "w2ed14", "w2ed16", "w2ed18")
  df[vars_to_standardize] <- scale(df[vars_to_standardize])
  return(df)
}

BP.3_impute_list <- lapply(BP.3_impute_list, standardize_vars)

# Create new total variables in each imputed dataset


create_total_vars <- function(df) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(w1_eddi_total = rowSums(df[, c("w1binge", "w1bingechar", "w1ed8a", "w1ed10a", "w1ed11a", "w1ed14", "w1ed16", "w1ed18")], na.rm = TRUE),
           w2_eddi_total = rowSums(df[, c("w2binge", "w2bingechar", "w2ed8a", "w2ed10a", "w2ed11a", "w2ed14", "w2ed16", "w2ed18")], na.rm = TRUE))
  return(df)
}

BP.3_impute_list <- lapply(BP.3_impute_list, create_total_vars)

However, the code for the formatting into long form does not work:
pivot.the.data.please<-function(df){
  
df<-subset(df, select= -c(w1binge, w1bingechar, w1ed8a, w1ed10a, w1ed11a, w1ed14, w1ed16, w1ed18, w2binge, w2bingechar, w2ed8a, w2ed10a, w2ed11a, w2ed14, w2ed16, w2ed18))

eddi = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
     cols = contains("eddi"), 
     names_to = "Time", # why is this in quotes?
     values_to = "EDDI Total") %>%  
  mutate(Time = gsub("_eddi_total", "", Time))
eddi<-subset(eddi, select= -c(w1_thinideal:w2_bodycompare))

thin_ideal = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("thinideal"),
    names_to = "Time",
    values_to = "ThinIdeal") %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub("_thinideal", "", Time))
thin_ideal<-subset(thin_ideal, select= -c(w1_bodydis:w2_eddi_total))

bodydis = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("bodydis"),
    names_to = "Time",
    values_to = "BodyDis") %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub("_bodydis", "", Time))
bodydis<-subset(bodydis, select= -c(w1_thinideal, w2_thinideal, w1_negaff:w2_eddi_total))

negaff = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("negaff"),
    names_to = "Time",
    values_to = "NegAff") %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub("_negaff", "", Time))
negaff<-subset(negaff, select= -c(w1_thinideal:w2_bodydis, w1_comm:w2_eddi_total))

comm = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("comm"),
    names_to = "Time",
    values_to = "comm") %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub("_comm", "", Time))
comm<-subset(comm, select= -c(w1_thinideal:w2_negaff, w1_bodycompare:w2_eddi_total))

bodycompare = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("bodycompare"),
    names_to = "Time",
    values_to = "bodycompare") %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub("_bodycompare", "", Time))
bodycompare<-subset(bodycompare, select= -c(w1_thinideal:w2_comm, w1_eddi_total:w2_eddi_total))

merged_1 <- merge(eddi,thin_ideal, by = c("Participant_ID_New", "ParticipantCondition", "DataWave", "location", "Age_", "Time" ))
merged_2 <- merge(merged_1,bodydis, by = c("Participant_ID_New", "ParticipantCondition", "DataWave", "location", "Age_", "Time" ))
merged_3 <- merge(merged_1,negaff, by = c("Participant_ID_New", "ParticipantCondition", "DataWave", "location", "Age_", "Time" ))
merged_4 <- merge(merged_3,comm, by = c("Participant_ID_New", "ParticipantCondition", "DataWave", "location", "Age_", "Time" ))
merged_5 <- merge(merged_4,bodycompare, by = c("Participant_ID_New", "ParticipantCondition", "DataWave", "location", "Age_", "Time" ))

return(merged_5)
}

BP.3_pivoted.please <- lapply(BP.3_impute_list, pivot.the.data.please)

And R gives back the following error:
Error in build_longer_spec(data, !!cols, names_to = names_to, values_to = values_to,  :
10.
stop(fallback)
9.
signal_abort(cnd, .file)
8.
abort(glue::glue("`cols` must select at least one column."))
7.
build_longer_spec(data, !!cols, names_to = names_to, values_to = values_to,
names_prefix = names_prefix, names_sep = names_sep, names_pattern = names_pattern,
names_ptypes = names_ptypes, names_transform = names_transform)
6.
pivot_longer.data.frame(., cols = contains("eddi"), names_to = "Time",
values_to = "EDDI Total")
5.
pivot_longer(., cols = contains("eddi"), names_to = "Time", values_to = "EDDI Total")
4.
mutate(., Time = gsub("_eddi_total", "", Time))
3.
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("eddi"), names_to = "Time",
values_to = "EDDI Total") %>% mutate(Time = gsub("_eddi_total",
"", Time))
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
1.
lapply(BP.3_impute_list, pivot.the.data.please)


The code works when I try to apply it to just one specific dataset at a time and subset df for the name of the specific dataframe, but when I try to apply it to all 50 it does not work. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

The message 'cols' must select at least one column. indicates that your first pivot_longer could not find the two columns to turn into long format via contains("eddi"). Did you inspect the output of create_total_vars(...)?
